# TF history - prompt user

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs

I want to prompt only username/author of last changeset. It is possible?

```
tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we can **prompt only** the username/author of the latest changeset by running the History command. Basically, the command will list the `Changeset`, `User`,`Date`and `Comment`. See [History command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/history-command?view=azure-devops#get-history-of-the-last-five-changes-to-all-items-in-a-folder) for details.
[image]

However you can try to write a script to run the command and retrieve the Author only if possible.

Besides, you can also achieve that by calling the [Get Changesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get-changesets?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API in a script.

Below PowerShell script for your reference:

```
$collectionurl = "https://xxx/DefaultCollection"
$project = "ProjectName"
$user = ""
$token = "PAT"

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$changeseturl = "$collectionurl/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.itemPath=$/$project&api-version=6.0"

$result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $changeseturl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value | Select -first 1  

Write-host "The last changeset author is:" $result.author.displayName
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem. I found a solution on how to get the number of last changeset in a quick way and thought it would work with the author. However, this solution is also great.